# Api response size is bigger ASP NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I am working on application in which I am calling simple API with Parameters which response is 95 MB and it took too much to load the response due its size the query is working perfectly but I really don't know why is the response so heavy. I am attaching my API code and also Postman response size and time.

```
[HttpGet("getsensorsspecifications")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSensorsSpecifications(int deviceId = 0, int companyId = 0)
        {
            var response = new Response();
            try
            {
                var model = new SensorSpecificationsViewModel();

                var getSensorsSpecifications = await _context.SensorRecognitionSpecEoi
                    .Include(x => x.SensorRecognitionSpec)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Device)
                    .Include(x => x.EoiType)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.EoiTypeCategory)
                    .Where(x => 
                    x.IsDeleted == 0
                    && x.SensorRecognitionSpec.DeviceId == deviceId
                   // && x.CompanyId == companyId
                    && x.SensorRecognitionSpec.IsDeleted == 0
                    && x.SensorRecognitionSpec.Device.IsDeleted == 0).ToListAsync();
                var monTypes = await _context.EoiType.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == 0).ToListAsync();

                if (getSensorsSpecifications?.Count > 0)
                {
                    model.SensorSpecificationsDetails = getSensorsSpecifications;
                    model.MonitoringTypes = monTypes;
                    response.StatusCode = StatusType.Success;
                    response.Result = model;
                }
                else
                {
                    response.StatusCode = StatusType.NotFound;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
                response.StatusCode = StatusType.ServerError;

            }
            // return response;
            return Ok(response);
        }
```

[image]

I am binding to list which contain plan data one is like 140 records and the other is 35 records only. Though it contain image URLs only.

Comment: What about trying to use pagination,and then you only need to pass part of the records according to the pagesize and pagenumber?

Comment: Yes but here pagination is not required I need to pass the response as it is